# ExpressJs: Wrong api endpoint triggered

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this api request:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/courses/get_public_course_data_by_id?course_id=454545
```

And I have these two ExpressJs routes:

```
router.get("/:id", (req, res) => {});
router.get("/get_public_course_data_by_id", (req, res) => {});
```

For some reason, it's always the first endpoint that gets triggered and not the second.

Comment: How does Express know about the `api/courses/` part of the route?

Comment: @Christian It's taken care of in server.js file

Answer (score 4):

You need to add static route before the dynamic route

**Like This:**

```
router.get("/get_public_course_data_by_id", (req, res) => {}); // 1st this
router.get("/:id", (req, res) => {}); // then this
```

The reason is, node router assuming `get_public_course_data_by_id` <-- this as `id` and processing the request accordingly and `get_public_course_data_by_id` is never executed.